# ¿Como renombrar las tablas que crea el EF por default?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

¿Se puede renombrar las tablas que crea el EF por defecto? al momento de crear un proyecto con algún mecanismo de autenticacion se crean automáticamente x cantidad de tablas que corresponden al sistema de logeo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es *Identity* a lo que te refieres puedes renombrar las tablas de la misma forma que se renombrar normalmente en **EF** cuando no quieres utilizar las convenciones por defecto o simplemente por que el modelo no debe tener los mismos nombres de las entidades de la aplicaciones.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("MisIdentidades");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("MisUsuarios");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("MisRoles");
}
```

Esto se hace sobrescribiendo el método onModelCreate en el contexto de EF como se puede ver en [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-asp-net-identity)